# auto-binding for panelSelectedChanged

Tags: polymer

```
    <template is="auto-binding">
        <core-drawer-panel drawerWidth="180px" rightDrawer forceNarrow selected="{{panelSelected}}">
        </core-drawer-panel>
    </template>

    <script>
        var t = document.querySelector('template');
        t.panelSelectedChanged=function(){
         console.log('panelSelectedChange', this.panelSelected)
        }
    </script>
```

Is there a way to use the ...Changed feature in a autobinding? I can not wrap it in a polymer element because it will break the other js frameworks around it.

EDIT:
The answer I received from Jeff works perfect, but also want to point out it has some non intuitive behavior

```
        t.addEventListener('template-bound', function() {
            document.querySelector('core-drawer-panel').addEventListener('core-select', function(e) {
                console.log('Selection changed:', e.detail.isSelected)
                console.log('Selection changed:', e.target.selected)
            })
        })
```

On open drawer

```
Selection changed: false 
Selection changed: drawer 
Selection changed: true 
Selection changed: drawer
```

On close drawer

```
Selection changed: false
Selection changed: main
Selection changed: true 
Selection changed: main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself, since I don't have a working example that illustrates the use of `<core-drawer-panel>`, but I can see that `<core-drawer-panel>` [includes](https://github.com/Polymer/core-drawer-panel/blob/master/core-drawer-panel.html#L88) a `<core-selector>` element which maintains the `selected` state.

Based on the docs for `<core-selector>`, the [`core-select` event](https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-docs/index.html#core-selector.events.core-select) should be fired whenever the selection state changes.

Therefore, you should be able to listen for that event and figure out when things have changed based on that, like (untested):

```
  document.querySelector('template').addEventListener('template-bound', function() {
    document.querySelector('core-drawer-panel').addEventListener('core-select', function(e) {
      console.log('Selection changed:', e.detail);
    });
  });
```

Alternatively, you can always use [`observe-js`](https://github.com/polymer/observe-js) (which is pulled in as part of the Polymer library) to detect when arbitrary variables change outside of a Polymer element. You can use a [PathObserver](https://github.com/polymer/observe-js#pathobserver) to observe changes to `{ t: 'panelSelected' }` in your example.

I think the approach of listening for events when possible is cleaner in this particular case, but the observer approach is a more general solution to the problem and is directly related to the `panelSelectedChanged` handler that you'd get within a Polymer element.

Comment: Nice :) Don't know how you figured that out but the events are working :P

Comment: Well... unfortunately the only way I was able to figure it out was by reading the source code and knowing how core-selector worked. I will file a bug for the docs.

Comment: https://github.com/Polymer/core-drawer-panel/pull/33 filed to get the docs updated, FYI.